# Different fontsizes for tick labels of x- and y-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to have tick labels with different font size on x- and y-axis.

My first try was:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel', {labelslist}, 'FontSize',16)
```

but it does not work, at least on with my version (2014a on Windows10). For some reason it changes the label font size on both axis.

Does anyone know how to do it?

**minimal example:**

```
A=[1 2 3; 2 3 4; 2 3 4; 1 1 1];

figure
bar([1:size(A,1)], A, 'BarWidth', 2)
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'1','2','3','4'},'FontSize',16)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try passing the axes handle directly to `set` rather than using `gca`?

Comment: @Suever how can I do that?

Comment: Store them when you create the axes. `hax1 = axes(); hax2 = axes(); set(hax1, 'FontSize', 25); set(hax2, 'FontSize', 8)`

Comment: thank you. but the result is the same. also a bit more messy.. it seems to write a second set of ticklabels over the one I specify. I'll edit the post with the code I use.

Comment: Ok so if you just copy pasted the code I wrote then yes it's messy. Try this instead: `hax1= subplot(1,2,1); set(hax1, 'FontSize', 24); hax2 = subplot(1,2,2); set(hax2, 'FontSize', 12)`. Also what OS?

Comment: In the image you just posted you only have one axes.

Comment: mmm.. I meant x-axis and y-axis. that's why I wasn't understanding your code. sorry.
my problem is that when I change the font size on the x-axis it changes also on the y-axis

Comment: yes that's how it works. You can't change it unless you manually draw text. In newer versions of MATLAB this is maybe possible using undocumented features.

Comment: it is not said in the documentation. thanks!

Comment: Why is it downvoted? It's an appropriate question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `axes` objects on top of each other, one for **x** and one for **y**:

```
%// example figure
A = [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 2 3 4; 1 1 1];
figure
bar([1:size(A,1)], A, 'BarWidth', 1)

%// handle
ax1 = gca;
%// fontsize of y-axis, deactivate, x-axis
set(ax1,'XTick',[],'FontSize',24)
%// create second identical axis and link it to first one
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1, 'Position'),'Color','none');
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy')
%// fontsize of x-axis, deactivate, y-axis
set(ax2,'YTick',[],'FontSize',12)
```

[image]

---

Regarding your comment, don't mix up the handles:

```
%// handle
ax1 = gca;
%// fontsize of y-axis, deactivate, x-axis
set(ax1,'XTick',[],'YTick',0:4,'YTickLabel',{'ZERO','ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR'},'FontSize',24)
%// create second identical axis and link it to first one
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1, 'Position'),'Color','none');
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy')
%// fontsize of x-axis, deactivate, y-axis
set(ax2,'YTick',[],'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'one','two','three','four'},'FontSize',12)
```

[image]

Comment: @shamalaia have a look at my edit, it's better to deactivate the ticks and not just the ticklabels.

Comment: do you also know how to change the xticklabel? I cannot.  `set(ax2,'YTick',[1:4],'FontSize',12)` `set(ax2,'xTicklabel',{'one','two','three','four'},'FontSize',12)`  just repeats the sequence

Comment: @shamalaia don't mix up the handles! Have a look at my edit.